# xUnit.net does not capture console output

Tags: xunit.net

I just started testing xUnit.net, but it doesn't seem to capture any output (Console, Debug, Trace), as I would have expected.

Is that possible? I am using a sample .NET 4.0 class-library with xUnit.net 1.8.

Comment: Xunit official documentation suggests to use ITestOutputHelper output parameter -https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output

Answer (score -14, accepted):

In general, it's a bad road to go down to be reliant on logging *and* tests. The pass/fail should be the outcome of the tests. And they simply shouldn't get to the stage where there's enough stuff going on that looking at a trace will be necessary.

The `xunit.gui.exe` shows Console and Trace output, `xunit.console.exe` does not. If it's important, you could hook up a TraceListener which redirects to a file by making appropriate standard .NET config entries (Theres' a `FileWriterTraceListener` which you should be able to hook in if you google it).

---

UPDATE: As discussed in [his blog post](http://dhickey.ie/2015/06/02/capturing-log-output-in-tests-with-xunit2/), Damian Hickey has a good example of a possible substitute - wiring logging to the xUnit 2 `ITestOutputHelper` as demonstrated in https://github.com/damianh/CapturingLogOutputWithXunit2AndParallelTests/blob/master/src/Lib.Tests/Tests.cs

UPDATE 2: In some cases, one can add logging and feed it to the `ITestOutputHelper` without involving `LogContext` by using a simple adapter as follows (I only have it in F#, sorry):

```
// Requirement: Make SUT depend on Serilog NuGet
// Requirement: Make Tests depend on Serilog.Sinks.Observable

type TestOutputAdapter(testOutput : Xunit.Abstractions.ITestOutputHelper) =
    let formatter = Serilog.Formatting.Display.MessageTemplateTextFormatter(
        "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}", null);
    let write logEvent =
        use writer = new System.IO.StringWriter()
        formatter.Format(logEvent, writer);
        writer |> string |> testOutput.WriteLine
    member __.Subscribe(source: IObservable<Serilog.Events.LogEvent>) =
        source.Subscribe write

let createLogger hookObservers =
    LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Observers(Action<_> hookObservers)
        .CreateLogger()
let createTestOutputLogger (output: ITestOutputHelper) =
    let adapter = TestOutputAdapter testOutputHelper
    createLogger (adapter.Subscribe >> ignore)

type Tests(testOutputHelper) =
    let log = createTestOutputLogger testOutputHelper

    [<Fact>] let feedToSut () =
        // TODO pass log to System Under Test either as a ctor arg or a method arg
```

The difference with this approach vs using the log context is that logging to the global [contextualized] Serilog `Logger` will not get picked up.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I was using xunit.console.exe.

I am aware that it is not a good solution, and it wasn't really the intended use. The reason I needed it was to debug some string operations while creating a new class using TDD.

Comment: I personally would just set xunit.console.exe as the startup project in the debugger in that case. BTW TeamCity and other similar run environments do pick up test output as you're looking for

Comment: @downvoter Why? (BTW in V2, there's planned work to stop the data being swallowed...)

Comment: [Missing citation for talk of removal of output capture in V2](https://xunit.codeplex.com/discussions/390453) ([Note the GUI runner, which is the only one that does any of this is being spun out of the Core xunit offering](https://xunit.codeplex.com/discussions/459481))

Comment: "In general, it's a bad road to go down to be reliant on logging and tests." - true, but using Console.Writeline to output stuff WHILE I'm setting up the tests is hugely helpful. Sometimes I'm testing a method and need to see the output of the method (for example if something serialized correctly when doing custom serialization) to insert back into the test to compare against.

Comment: Switched to NUnit, which captures stdout. If a test fails, it's greatly important to know what's going on in the production code, in which case the logging becomes important. Injecting any test framework specific dependency into the production code just so I can see the output while running tests is just ridiculous. And I found that when people start telling you "xxx is a bad idea...", although sounds cool, it usually is an excuse to the incompetency of the tool you're having issue with.

Comment: @KFL Don't worry, there's no conspiracy - the xUnit authors are very capable of writing stuff, but have a very intentional design philosophy which can result in things people lean on (too much) being left out. Multithreading, decoupling and general FP concepts all point down the road of not using console outputs. It's perfectly feasible to write an adapter which would make it kinda work (would bet one is a search away) - but you will lose the ability to do multithreaded running. I personally would do the necessary to work without it though. Trick: `Debug.WriteLine` and use SysInternals DbgView

Comment: So the xUnit authors think that having tests that fail with no information on WHY is a great design?

Comment: I disagree strongly on your comment regarding "it's a bad road to go down to be reliant on logging and tests".  We run integration tests (apart from unit tests), that if broken, it is extremely helpful to see the logging information to understand what exactly failed before further investigation.

Comment: @z0mbi3 I'm not saying for one second that logs are not _helpful_. I'm saying that a meaningful test should not be _reliant_ on logs - it should do something simple and make a clear and meaningful assertion. I do appreciate that for meandering system / integration tests, logs can play a vital part in making it be possible to determine what led to the failure; however in that case, having a set of smaller tests that each test simple things is more sustainable and will lead to a better system. In short, a test failure should tend to have a single obvious cause, and not be a murder mystery.

Comment: @z0mbi3 Updated to show some techniques that may be of interest. Unlike writing to Console/Debug/Trace and capturing that, explicitly passing a logger to the SUT (or going full hog and using the Enricher and LogContext like in Damian's example) provides a way for you to get correctly attributed information without having to disaggregate interleaved output from a log file.

Comment: "In general its a bad idea to both turn the wheel of your car and also look out the windshield to see which direction you are going"

Answer (score 81):

The situation has changed a little with xUnit.net 2. I know the question is about an earlier version, but as people will land here having performed the upgrade, I thought it was worth pointing this out.

In order to see some kind of output in the test output in version 2 you will need to take a dependency in your test class (via a constructor argument) on an instance of `Xunit.Abstractions.ITestOutputHelper`, then use the `WriteLine` method on this interface. E.g.:

```cs
public class MyTestSpec
{
  private readonly ITestOutputHelper _testOutputHelper;

  public MyTestSpec(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper)
  {
    _testOutputHelper = testOutputHelper;
  }

  [Fact]
  public void MyFact()
  {
    _testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Hello world");
  }
}
```

You could choose to hook up your logging framework to this interface, perhaps by injecting an `ILog` implementation that forwarded all calls to `ITestOutpuHelper`.

I acknowledge that you won't want to do this by default, but for diagnostic purposes from time to time it can be quite useful. This is especially true where your tests only fail on some cloud based build & test server!

Comment: By the way, ITestOutputHelper is found in the Xunit.Abstractions namespace.

Comment: [official example code](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/blob/master/TestOutputExample/Example.cs). It still works on .NET core projects.

Comment: What if you already had a custom object instance (i.e. `MyDatabaseFixture`) being passed in this MyTestSpec constructor instead of `ITestOutputHelper`?

Comment: SO should allow most voted answer display above accepted answer.

Comment: I'm not seeing the output when running `dotnet test`.  Is there a secret to using this interface while running the .NET Core test runner?  (EDIT: looks like the log is displayed _only after_ an assert fails, so the intent appears to be logs are only accessible for debugging a failure, which I can live with, begrudgingly.)

Comment: @JonathanB. Run with `dotnet test --logger "console;verbosity=detailed"`

Comment: ITestOutputHelper cannot be configured inside xUnit extensibility classes, so its usability is severly limited.

Answer (score 63):

This can help if your `Console.Write` is embedded deep down some class hierarchy that you don't want to refactor:

```cs
    public MyTestClass(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        var converter = new Converter(output);
        Console.SetOut(converter);
    }

    private class Converter : TextWriter
    {
        ITestOutputHelper _output;
        public Converter(ITestOutputHelper output)
        {
            _output = output;
        }
        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return Encoding.Whatever; }
        }
        public override void WriteLine(string message)
        {
            _output.WriteLine(message);
        }
        public override void WriteLine(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            _output.WriteLine(format, args);
        }

        public override void Write(char value)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("This text writer only supports WriteLine(string) and WriteLine(string, params object[]).");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you use any of TextWriter's  the other methods. For example, `Write`?

Comment: @NechemiaHoffmann, it's a long time ago, but I believe that internally they all call down to these overloads of WriteLine

Comment: No it's the other way around. Overriding Write(char) will make WriteLine(string) work but not the other way around. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712607/implementing-a-derived-class-of-textwriter

Comment: I had to override `Write(string? value)` to get this to work properly with LLBLGen trace logs, i.e. 

`public override void Write(string? value)
 {
     _output.WriteLine(value);
 }`

Answer (score 7):

I used Console.SetOut to output Console.Writes to .NET Test Log (in Visual Studio Code).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;

namespace UnitTest
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        private ITestOutputHelper output;
        public TestClass(ITestOutputHelper output)
        {
            this.output = output;
        }

        public class ConsoleWriter : StringWriter
        {
            private ITestOutputHelper output;
            public ConsoleWriter(ITestOutputHelper output)
            {
                this.output = output;
            }

            public override void WriteLine(string m)
            {
                output.WriteLine(m);
            }
        }

        [Fact]
        public void TestName()
        {
            Console.SetOut(new ConsoleWriter(output));
            Assert.True(ToBeTested.Foo());
        }



        public class ToBeTested
        {
            public static bool Foo()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Foo uses Console.WriteLine!!!");
                return true;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

[image]

But it is easier to just run the test via console

```
dotnet test
```

There the output will be shown without any modifications of test class.
[image]

It is different since the .NET Test Log-window uses the TRX-format (Visual Studio Test Results File), see

```
dotnet test -h | grep logger
```

For more information about TRX.

Comment: for some reason this only works when the test fails...

Answer (score 1):

This was a simple solution I've done using a StringBuilder to capture the output and only output it in case of test failure:

```
        [Fact]
        public void UnitTest1()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            try
            {
                // ... the test code ...
                sb.AppendLine("Put your debug information here.");
                int expected = 1;
                int actual = 2;
                // What I really want to check:
                Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
            }
            // Catch exceptions from the Assert
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("The original failure:");
                sb.AppendLine(e.Message);
                sb.AppendLine(e.StackTrace);
                Assert.True(false, sb.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Since only the Xunit Assert.True() method takes a message, I use it in the catch and provide the "log" information via its message, which you will see if the test fails.

You can get rid of the try/catch if you only use Assert.True() in the test and provide sb.ToString() as the message.

Comment: Xunit does not offer a decent way for this, so your approach help me!

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution as found here: https://xunit.codeplex.com/discussions/211566

Simply add this to your constructor or method where you want debugging output:

```
Debug.Listeners.Add(new DefaultTraceListener());
```

Comment: For those tuning in later, this is no longer a recommended practice. See http://xunit.github.io/docs/capturing-output.html.

Comment: Oh man those xunit guys, if it's not complicated enough it ain't xunit -.- Ofc there is no IMessageSink on .Net Core.... MsTestV2 to the rescue!

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I landed here with the same question. Here's what I ended up with. I hope it helps someone else.

[How to write a custom target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-target)

```csharp
    /// <summary>
    ///     Use this to output NLog information when running test cases.
    /// </summary>
    [Target("XUnit")]
    public class XUnitTarget : TargetWithLayout
    {
        [RequiredParameter] public ITestOutputHelper OutputHelper { get; set; }

        protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
        {
            var logMessage = Layout.Render(logEvent);
            OutputHelper.WriteLine(logMessage);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Call this in the test where you wish to enable logging.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="testOutputHelper">The xUnit output helper from the test.</param>
        public static void Configure(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper)
        {
            var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
            var xUnitTarget = new XUnitTarget
            {
                OutputHelper = testOutputHelper
            };
            config.AddTarget("xUnit", xUnitTarget);
            config.AddRule(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, xUnitTarget);
            LogManager.Configuration = config;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only method you'll need to override is Write(char[] buffer, int index, int count). All other methods will end up using this one.

```
public class TestOutputWriter : TextWriter
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper _output;

    public TestOutputWriter(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        _output = output;
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding => Encoding.UTF8;

    public override void Write(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        _output.WriteLine(new string(buffer, index, count));
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
Console.SetOut(new TestOutputHelper(outputHelper));
```

The only thing you'd might want to do is some 'magic' buffering when the character buffer doesn't contain a new line ('\n') as ITestOutputHelper only contains a WriteLine method.